# vim: Automatically advance to next misspelled word after taking action on current one

Tags: vim, spell-checking

I want to configure vim so that when I perform some spellcheck related action that changes state (`zg`, `z=` where one option was chosen, etc.) that the cursor will advance to the next misspelled word as if I had typed `]s`.  How would I go about this?

Comment: `noremap zg zg]s` for the one, at least.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? By showing your attempts and describing what parts you are having difficulty with, we get a better understanding of your proficiency and can give a more precise answer. As it stands, it just looks like you've posted a requirement and want someone to write your code for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `zg` mapping should be just simple as @U2744 SNOWFLAKE suggested:

```
noremap zg zg]s
```

I imagine the tricky part is coming up with a mapping for `z=` that will do `]s` afterwards. Put the following in your `~/.vimrc` file:

```
nnoremap z= :<c-u>call SpellNext()<cr>z=
function! SpellNext()
  augroup SpellNext
    autocmd!
    autocmd CursorMoved <buffer> execute 'normal! ]s' | autocmd! SpellNext
  augroup END
endfunction
```

Note: I have not tested this. This method will not work if you do not change the word as it will not trigger the `CursorMoved` event in that case.

Comment: @IngoKarkat, I adapted this form a similar trick to activate `'spell'` just for `z=` then promptly restore `'spell'`. Personally I think executing `z=` shouldn't require `set spell`